# Intento evitar que se pulsen letras pero se cuela la "e"

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net

Tengo esta funcion javascript:

```html
function NumericTextBoxValidator(event) {
    console.log(event.keyCode);
    return (
        ((event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57) ||     // Números 
        (event.keyCode >= 96 && event.keyCode <= 105) ||    // Números Pad numerico
        event.keyCode == 110 ||                             // Punto pad numerico
        event.keyCode == 9 ||                               // Tabulador
        event.keyCode == 8 ||                               // Borrar
        event.keyCode == 46 ||                              // Suprimir
        event.keyCode == 37 ||                              // Flecha izquierda
        event.keyCode == 38 ||                              // Flecha arriba
        event.keyCode == 39 ||                              // Flecha derecha
        event.keyCode == 40 ||                              // Flecha abajo
        event.keyCode == 188 ||                             // Coma
        event.keyCode == 190 ||                             // Punto 
        (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 86) ||           // Pegar
        (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 88) ||           // Cortar
        (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 67))&&           // Copiar
        // teclas ignoradas a mano porque se saltan el chequeo
        event.keyCode != 69 &&                              // Letra E
        event.keyCode != 107 &&                             // Simbolo "+"
        event.keyCode != 187 &&                             // Simbolo "+"
        event.keyCode != 109 &&                             // Simbolo "-"
        event.keyCode != 189                                // Simbolo "-"
    );
}
```

El control ASP.NET sería este:

```html
<asp:TextBox ID="tbxNumero" runat="server" MaxLength="3" NumberFormat-GroupSeparator="" NumberFormat-DecimalDigits="0" Type="Number" onkeydown = "NumericTextBoxValidator(event)">
```

A pesar de esta funcion y de lo que añadí al final, la letra "e" (mayúscula o minúscula) y los simbolos "-" y "+" se pintan igualmente.

¿A alguien se le ocurre que se me escapa?

Un saludo.

Comment: solo quieres permitir letras??

Answer (score 0):

creo que hay un problema en la lógica de la condición, pues lo que estás indicando en esta parte:

```
(event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 67))&&           // Copiar
    // teclas ignoradas a mano porque se saltan el chequeo
    event.keyCode != 69 &&                              // Letra E
    event.keyCode != 107 &&                             // Simbolo "+"
    event.keyCode != 187 &&                             // Simbolo "+"
    event.keyCode != 109 &&                             // Simbolo "-"
    event.keyCode != 189
```

Es que la combinación de teclas, además de copiar y pegar también contenga la letra E, + y -.

Este caso sólo devuelve true en caso de que pulses Ctrl y c y e y + y -

Deberías separar organizar todo con OR's, como a continuación:

```
(event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 67))||           // Copiar
    // teclas ignoradas a mano porque se saltan el chequeo
    event.keyCode != 69 ||                              // Letra E
    event.keyCode != 107 ||                             // Simbolo "+"
    event.keyCode != 187 ||                             // Simbolo "+"
    event.keyCode != 109 ||                             // Simbolo "-"
    event.keyCode != 189
```